# Operator || or | cannot be used

Tags: java

I am trying to get this code to compile, but my compiler (BlueJ)is telling me the || cannot be applied to java.lang.string.java.lang.string

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

class Hi {
public static void main (String [] args){

String Answer;
Answer = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Who is a troll?");
if (Answer.equals ("null")) 
{
 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You forgot to enter an answer before pressing 'ok'.");
} 
else if (Answer.equals("Bob" || "Bob" || "Charlie Sheen"))
{
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your answer is incorrect.");
} 
else
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Yes, " + Answer + ", is definitely a douchebag.");

System.exit(0); // not needed to run 

}
}
```

Thank you sooo much for the help

Comment: What do you expect `"Bob" || "Bob" || "Charlie Sheen"` to evaluate to?

Comment: All the answers given here are valid, but don't you think guys it would be quite fun to be able to comparte strings in a way Mot39 suggested (i.e "(Answer.equals("Bob" || "Bob" || "Charlie Sheen"))")?

Comment: @WojtekO.: You want the Icon language for that, it's the first concept they introduce in [the introduction](http://www.cs.arizona.edu/icon/intro.htm).

Answer (score 8):

You can't do it like that. The `||` operator expects two boolean operands, and yours are strings. You have to check each equality separately:

```
if (answer.equals("Bob") || answer.equals("Charlie Sheen")) {
}
```

A few sidenotes:

- variable names should be lowercase (by convention).
- you shouldn't supply the same string ("Bob") twice.
- `null` is not the same as `"null"`. You should compare `answer == null`. If you try to call `.equals(..)` on a `null` object, you'll get an exception

Comment: Thank you guys so much, I guess that made sense in my head but not in actuality.

Answer (score 5):

Try

`if (Answer.equals("Bob") || Answer.equals("Charle") {}`

As Bozho points out, please stick to java coding standards as described in the [Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html#367) section of the Java Coding Conventions.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot apply the logical OR operator to String operands.

Try:

```
if (Answer.equals("Bob") || Answer.equals("Charlie Shee"))
```

Answer (score 1):

The previous answers will work.

```
if (Answer.equals("Bob") || Answer.equals("Charlie Shee"))
```

But it is better to take the good habit of writting like this:

```
if ("Bob".equals(Answer) || "Charlie Shee".equals(Answer))
```

to avoid an eventual crash if Answer becomes null.

Answer (score 1):

As others indicated: this won't work as it isn't valid syntax for equals. A less verbose solution could be:

```
if (Arrays.asList("Bob", "Bob", "Charlie Sheen").contains(Answer))
```