# using or operator on String in java

Tags: java

I want to check a string with a multiple values using or operator , is that possible ?

```
like if(str.equals("A" || "B" || "C")){
//do this 
}
else if(str.equals("D" || "E" || "F")){
//do that
}
```

I am getting error while compiling, that || can not be used in string

Comment: You have to do an individual check for each. `str.equals("A") || str.equals("B")`

Comment: The `||` operator works on booleans, which strings aren't. That aside, if it's a single character, perhaps using a character and a `switch` would be a better option. If there are a large number of possible matches, you might want to change the decision strategy altogether, though.

Comment: This question has occurred repeatedly before, including  [Operator || or | cannot be used](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7862437/operator-or-cannot-be-used) and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18112464/java-bad-operand-type/18112494

Comment: @AndyThomas Wow, thanks for finding that duplicate! It is amazing how the same syntax error gets reproduced almost verbatim by different programmers.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight - You're welcome. I remembered seeing another duplicate within the past few months, but stopped looking after finding those two.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also use a `switch` in Java 7:

```
switch (str) {
case "A":
case "B":
case "C":
    // do this
    break;
case "D":
case "E":
case "F":
    // do that
    break;
}
```

This might be more readable if you have many strings you want to compare against. For reference, see the "Using Strings in switch Statements" section of the [`switch` Statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) tutorial.

Comment: Put all the `case:` on the same line.

Answer (score 11):

`if(str.equals("A") || str.equals("B") || str.equals("C")){ .... }`

You have to separate your conditions.

Comment: What is the equivalent of this js code in java: `const value = ""; const value = value1 || "new-value";`?

Answer (score 5):

You do not need an `OR` in this case: you can write the same condition like this:

```
if (Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C").contains(str)) {
    ...
}
```

This test is successful when the test string `str` is contained in the list specified in the call to `asList`, which conveniently takes a variable number of parameters.

Comment: I have 6 character to match, this look like better option

Comment: This is nice less verbose approach